# Error in Criteria Builder LIKE clause when escaping a character

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using *Spring Boot 3.1.2* with *Hibernate 6.2.6.Final* version with PostgreSQL and I've encountered a problem in *Criteria Builder* `like(Expression<String> x, String pattern, char escapeChar)` method (and equivalents).
The generated SQL query is invalid, when the escape char is set.

Example:

The criteria built with following code:

```
String searchTerm = "\\_";
cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + searchTerm + "%", '\\')
```

result in:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"`

and the generated query is: `select name from project where name like ? escape \`

Is that a bug on Hibernate's side or is it possible to format the query in criteria builder so its syntax is correct for PostgreSQL (which is I believe: `select name from project where name like ? escape '\'`, note the escape char is quoted in '')

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile. `"\_"` is an illegal escape. Either way, you probably need to have a double escape "\\\\", so that it's going into the SQL still correctly escaped.

Comment: I've edited the question :). However, the problem is that the escape character is a char, not a string, so you can't really use double escape

Comment: I have the same problem using Spring Data JPA repoository. For example I do not have special characters in search term, but I receive this query. `select id, name from table where name like '%test%' escape !`, and this is not valid query in MySQL. I saw that HQL is correct with quotes around `!`, but when it is transformed to real query string, it is missing quotes. This was correct in previous version of Hibernate.

Comment: We upgraded Spring Boot to 3.1.3 and Hibernate to 6.2.7.Final. Also we were using hypersistence-utils version 3.5.0. When we upgraded hypersistence-utils to 3.5.2, everything worked correctly. I am no sure is it something in some of those dependencies, but it fixed our problem, so maybe it will give you some idea for your problem. I think that Spring Boo and Hibernate Version upgrade did not have much effect, but just in case. Cheers.